# Python is unable to import library compiled with boost_python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have the following sample program:

```
// src/main.cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* func()
{
    return "String";
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bridge)
{
    boost::python::def("func", func);
}
```

When built using the following CMakeLists.txt, no compiler errors are given:

```
project(bridge)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
   )

# Include Python
#set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.5)
find_package(PythonLibs)
if (${PYTHONLIBS_FOUND})
    include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# Include Boost
find_package(Boost 1.61.0 COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
if (${Boost_FOUND})
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
endif()

# Enable C++ 11
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
add_compile_options("-lboost_python")

add_library(bridge SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(bridge ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(bridge ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

However, importing the shared library (libbridge.so) gives the following error:

```
/bin$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libbridge
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./libbridge.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE
```

I have compiled boost and boost_python without any problem, and other boost libraries are fully functional. What is wrong here?

*Edit*: In another post a solution was given by making the filename the same as the argument fed into `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`. After these modifications, the following error is now given by `import libbridge`:

```
ImportError: ./libbridge.so: invalid ELF header
```

Exporting the environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib` does not seem to create a difference.

Comment: Please provide output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from environment python is launched in. Ensure LD_LIBRARY_PATH is exported (in bash terms) and contains a location of boost_python*.so

Comment: @Basilevs I have tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib`. Now it gives another error. (The error persists even if `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty)

Comment: It seems you have multiple builds of boost installed. Try leaving only one.

Comment: And use matching headers

Comment: @Basilevs There is only one boost build located in `/usr/local`.

Comment: If LD_LIBRARY_PATH affects execution, there are different libraries in different folders. Have you checked system folders? You forgot to update question with new information.

Comment: @Basilevs I cleared the environment variables and the error is still invalid ELF header. I have checked `/usr/include` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`. They do not contain boost.

Comment: Don't look for shared libraries in include folders, look in /usr/lib,  for example.

Comment: @Basilevs The command `whereis libboost_system` gives only two locations: `/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a, /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so`.

Comment: There is no ELF errors in the question body

Comment: @Basilevs I appended the error to the end of the question.

Comment: `ldd libbridge.so` may give you a hint.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. The problem is due to Python version mismatch inside Boost. I decided to compile everything in Python 3 and it solves the problem. I proceeded as follows:

1. I uncommented the following line to the auto-generated `user-config.jam` located in `$BOOST_ROOT/tools/build/example/`

   using python : 3.5 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.5 : /usr/lib;
2. Boost.Python was built from scratch using the commands (executed in sudo to gain permission to `/usr/local`)

   $BOOST_ROOT : ./b2 --with-python --clean
   $BOOST_ROOT : ./b2 --with-python --install

I verified that the libraries are indeed Python 3 using

```
$BOOST_ROOT : nm -D stage/lib/libboost_python-3.so | grep PyClass_Type
```

No output should be given. If the library was compiled with Python 2, then `U PyClass_Type` would show up.

3. The `CMakeLists.txt` file in the sample project was slightly modified:

   set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.5) // uncommented
   find_package(Boost 1.61.0 COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED) // python3 instead of python
   add_compile_options("-lboost_python") // removed
4. Now `python3` (not `python`) should be able to link against the compiled `libbridge.so` library.