# Caffe Installation Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, caffe

I got this error while importing caffe library to python2.7

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/omer/caffe-master/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "/home/omer/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /home/omer/caffe-master/python/caffe/_caffe.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE
```

I have completed all steps

```
make all -j4
make test
make runtest
make pycaffe
make distribute
exporting PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python is unable to import library compiled with boost\_python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872830/python-is-unable-to-import-library-compiled-with-boost-python)

Comment: Pretty sure the root cause is the same as the duplicate. Try compiling for and using Python 3 if you can.

Comment: How to get rid off this duplicate issue??

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this commands

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev
```

Comment: I did all. Nothing changed. And I am facing this error again and again.